# How can i change a substring in a matched string in a file in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want the following change :

Original :

```
Format="%05dA1"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dB1"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dC1"
StartValue="2"
```

Modified:

```
Format="%05dA2"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dB2"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dC2"
StartValue="2"
```

I have tried the following regular expression but I was unable to get the what I wanted.

```
$main_course =~ s/05d\w{2}\d{1}/05d\w{2}$name/g
```

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Replacing all `1` by `2` within double quotes ?

Comment: Try this regex: `/%05d\w(\d)/g`  and advance value inside group 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increases last number by `1`

```
perl -pe 's| (%.+) (\d)|$1. ($2+1)|xe' input_file
```

Answer (score 5):

I am concerned that people are struggling with this. If you are running Perl 5 version 10 or later (and you should be because it's well over five years old) then you can usefully employ the `\K` sequence that **K**eeps anything to the left when doing a subtitution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  s/%05[a-z]{2}\K(\d)/$1+1/gie;
  print;
}

__DATA__
Format="%05dA1"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dB1"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dC1"
StartValue="2"
```

**output**

```
Format="%05dA2"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dB2"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dC2"
StartValue="2"
```

If you are stuck with an older version of Perl then just capture that first part and put it back again with

```
s/(%05[a-z]{2})(\d)/$1.($2+1)/gie;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 4 argument `substr`.  For example, to replace the single digit that follows `05d` and 2 word characters with the contents of `$StartValue`, you could do:

```
$Format =~ m/05d\w{2}\d/; substr( $Format, $-[0] + 5, 1, $StartValue );
```

The initial call to `m//` loads the `@-` array with the location of the match, and `substr` replaces the appropriate substring.

Answer (score 0):

What went wrong?

- Your regex `05d\w{2}\d{1}` matches 6 characters, so it won't match `05dA1` and co, you probably want `05d\w\d` or `05\w{2}\d` (`{1}` is unnecessary).
- Also the replacement side of `s` is not regex, so `\w{2}` means the escape sequence `\w` (or literal `w` if no such sequence exist) followed by a literal `2` enclosed in braces.

If you want to reuse captured string on the replacement side, you can use capture groups e.g. `$1`, or other special variables like `$&` (Note: perlre mentions using `$&` "may substantially slow your program").

For Perl v5.10 and above, you can do this

```
$main_course =~ s/05d\w\K\d/$name/g
```

- `\K` is a lookbehind assertion which means the substring matched by `05d\w` is not included in the string to be replaced by `s`

Comment: Using `\w` for an alpha is very sloppy.

Comment: @Borodin, that depends on how well the snippet correspond to the actual file. For all we know there could be a `%05d_1` somewhere down the line

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/(Format.*[A-Z])(\d+)/$1.($2+1)/ge;' your_file
```

Tested:

```
> cat temp
Format="%05dA1"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dB1"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dC1"
StartValue="2"
> perl -pe 's/(Format.*[A-Z])(\d+)/$1.($2+1)/ge;' temp
Format="%05dA2"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dB2"
StartValue="2"
Format="%05dC2"
StartValue="2"
>
```